# Either don't copy or fail when calling Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements or equivalent

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

The JNI `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements` family of functions have signatures of this form for accessing Java array elements from C:

`NativeType *Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements(JNIEnv *env, ArrayType array, jboolean *isCopy);`

`isCopy` is used to indicate if the returned data is a copy. Is there a way to call these functions (or similar functions) and either not copy or fail?

What I want to do from C is access a Java array in-place, if possible, and otherwise call one of the `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayRegion` family to copy the array data to a place of my choosing.

**Edit:** I suspect this can't be done at this point. If that's the case, I'm happy to accept an answer confirming that fact, especially if it can explain the rationale for why the JNI was designed this way.